# Show Facebook events with angular

Tags: facebook, angular, display

I want to display events on my website.

I take events from facebook with this :

infos.service.ts :

```
getEvents(link: string): Observable<any>{

let id = link.split('facebook.com/')[1].split('?')[0];
console.log("id ------> ",id);

return this.http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${id}?fields=events{name}&access_token=`)      
    .map(events => events.json());
}
```

After in home.component.ts :

```
onChange(e: Event) {

let value = e.target['value'];
this.service.getEvents(value).subscribe(event => {
  console.log('events: ', event);
})
    this.service.getEvents(value).subscribe((data) => this.events=data);

  }
}
```

And I use this in order to display :

```
 <ul>
    <li> {{ events | json}}</li>
</ul>
```

But it shows me that and I can't use *ngFor :

```
"events": { "data": [ { "name": "Qui veut partir à Ibiza avec la team Coke TV cet été ?", "id": "1039032149505674" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveLyon", "id": "891490744279264" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveToulouse", "id": "816021265181647" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveMontpellier", "id": "801781889934749" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveMarseille", "id": "1610198129252793" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveNantes", "id": "936652956376199" }, { "name": "MoveMyCity #MoveParis", "id": "1609074386008334" } ], "paging": { "cursors": { "before": "QVFIUmdUc21tQW80b0tzLVgtc3VtUHI5OFNxdlZAMaVUwZAW02R1JvbGs4ZAUVwTUpmbUNiSVJ5eTBHVXMwSkw4RkFQQWNzZA3o1eTgzN2hxUFVINnlzd1ZA1eE93", "after": "QVFIUjgtRUUwR29ud25QdlE2YmVhQ3BfZAXdsd1R2SDlqeWlaeEk5empwVlBWQ1VkOXFtUkF2VUVPQlhvMWlLaHdNZA2VXczBuQkpyc0o1V2dNQUdZAYjllVE1B" } } }, "id": "998589190158511" }
```

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would step into the JSON and extract the array:

```
return this.http.get('the url')      
    .map(events => events.json().events.data);
}
```

The component code would stay the same, then you can very well iterate your data:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
  {{event.name}}
</div>
```

If you do not want to extract only the array, but keep your code like it is, then you need to iterate like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events.events.data">
  {{event.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a plunker with what I assume is your JSON, so this is how you can get the user: http://plnkr.co/edit/93XEvi0dKcrjZ3PurB5J?p=preview